# Show/Hide angular component (i need to toggle(show or hide) these two angular components based on click)

Tags: angular

**i need to toggle(show or hide) these two angular components based on click**

```
<app-product-list ></app-product-list>
<app-service-list></app-service-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write code for the click to toggle a variable in the component called `foo` then your HTML can be like this:

```
<app-product-list *ngIf="this.foo"></app-product-list>
<app-service-list *ngIf="!this.foo"></app-service-list>
```

Details on `*ngIf` are at https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf